# How to make each Treeview Node have a related TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am trying to make a form in which the user fills in values. It is quite long. I wish to use an expandable tree to fit it into my one form. Is there any way to give each TreeView Node a TextBox by its side? Having the node text edited by itself is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the textbox for editing the node? or for secondary data? If the node, it can already be editable (Edit/BeginEdit or something). If secondary data, I would be quite tempted to push this into a single textbox that displays/edits the data for the current selected node. That may text-boxes is going to be confusing!

Alternatively, there are some treeview/grid combined controls available from 3rd parties. Might be a good fit. [Here's](http://www.binarymission.co.uk/) (look for `TreeListView`) a quick search hit (not a specific recommendation - just a search result).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the textBox in the TreeNode.Tag and then draw the textbox based on the actual TreeNode position.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use useless 3rd party controls, as they are native in Windows !
(in particular the TreeListView, which is native since NT 3.5)