# Set position of edit box in the TreeView

Tags: winforms, treeview, ownerdrawn

In WinForms, I would like to know if it is possible to programmatically set the position of the edit box in the TreeView, and if yes, how ?

Let me give more details.
We have an owner drawn TreeView (System.Windows.Forms.TreeView) with DrawMode set to OwnerDrawAll.
We draw an icon first, then the hierarchy, then the item-related icon and then the text.

```
[O] +- # Root 1
    |  |
[X] |  +- # Node 1
    |  |  |
[X] |  |  +- # SubNode 1
    |  |  |
[O] |  |  +- # SubNode 2
    |  |
[O] |  +- # Node 2
    |
[X] +- # Root 2
       |
[X]    +- # Node 3
```

On the above graph, the `[X]` and `[O]` are the represenations of the first icon, and the `#` symbol is the representation of the item-related icon.

The problem is, when editing the text using the regular TreeView way, by setting LabelEdit to true, then the Edit box is overlapping the icon (the # symbol on the graph) instead of being beside the icon, because we shifted the text rendering.
Another problem is that the place (rectangle) to click to make the edit box to appear is shifted too.

I tried to set the Indent property with an higher value and then shift my hierarchy, item-related icon and text rendering back to the left to keep it properly aligned, but in this case, indentation is doubled for each node:

It mathematically result in `[spacing = level * indent * 2]`

Where I need `[spacing = indent + (level * indent)]`

I just cannot set Indent property individually for each node, so this solution is not valid.

I tried to get the Edit box handle in the OnBeforeLabelEdit event, successfully, but then I figured out that I just cannot do anything usefull with it.

We are thinking about using a custom TextBox and position it ourself on the TreeView, but using the regular already implemented way is prefered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible `duplicate` of :- <http://stackoverflow.com/a/325412/763026>

Comment: No it's not.
The solution using a third party control is just impossible, as long as our custom TreeView is already quite complex and match the very specific requirements of our customer.
The solution with an independent TextBox is what I talked about at the end of my post, but it does not answer my original question.
Anyway thank you for your participation.